# How to make sure that user print the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where user can print or view the report. There is a button on the page. When user clicks on the button, a new tab with print window is opened. Here is the code.

```
elements.$printRegistry.on("click", function () {
    Registry.printRegistry();
});
```

Here is the `printRegistry` function:

```
var registryId = $("#registryId").val();
var printWindow = window.open("/Registry/Registry/PrintRegistry?registryId=" + registryId);
printWindow.print();
```

How i can assure that user has print the registry. I can't do this on click button because user may only view the page. I want to assure that user has print the page and mark a field in database. How i can do this?

Comment: `How i can assure that user has print the registry` Unfortunately you can't. JS gets no events or notifications that the print actually ocurred

Comment: if only we could control the users' PC with javascript... oh what a world would it be! :)

Comment: @Ted Nice one :).

Comment: What browser(s) are you targeting ? You might be able to accomplish this with some kind of 'active' content (I'm thinking some kind of Flash/ActiveX)

Comment: It's chrome, firefox and IE.

Comment: I would definitely not try to achieve that. Even if you could get a notification that the document is actually sent to the printer, there are still quite some factors which might prevent printing.
I think that you have to rethink what you actually want.

Comment: Try [**afterprint**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/afterprint) but ome browsers do not support it.

Comment: We had a similar system at a previous job. The way it was implemented, is that if any user had opened the file for printing, it was marked as 'printed' (not taking the actual print into account). It was not a bulletproof method, but this was the closest they could get.

Comment: @AlexSzabó thanks. I think i should also do this. There is no other method to confirm this.